# The type or namespace name could not be found in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, xamarin, dll, compiler-errors

I am trying to run Xamarin project in visual studio 2022. This project worked in visual studio2019.

I got error like this.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you install Xamarin? Or just Maui?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You have to install Xamarin for this to work!

Comment: @jack I installed Xamarin

Comment: Does it run wel if you create a new Xamarin project?

Comment: yes sure. I run new project

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to run Xamarin project in visual studio 2022. This project worked in visual studio2019. I got error like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrG9B.png).

Sometimes this situation occurs: strange errors may occur when a project is running with a new version of VS.

As a solution, you can create a new project and migrate the code into it.